# Calculating average intensity value of BW image using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a BW image. I have to calculate the average intensity of that image. For this I have to store individual intensity value of all pixels of that image then calculate average intensity. In this calculation I have to count only the non zero pixel's intensity value (full black pixel i.e. intensity value zero should not take in calculation). How can I do that?

Comment: use logical indexing to exclude zero valued pixels and `mean` to find the average so if your image is `I` then `mean(mean(I(I>0)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, but this doesn't work if any columns of the image are all 0!

```
  im=imread('imageBW.jpg');
  intensity=mean(sum(im)./sum(im~=0));
```

Comment: This doesn't work if any columns of the image are all 0.  If at least one column sums to 0, then you will get `NaN` as the result due to a `0/0` division error.  Dan's code in his comment is more suitable.

Comment: No problem.  If you change your code so that it works, I'll remove my downvote.  The downvote will still remain if you don't change it because this code will not work and is potentially dangerous for anyone who uses it.